# use same background lines for image & list items

Tags: html, css

if you run  below code snippet, you can see as below image as in [this link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers.html)

[image]

there is separation between image and list items with background line. i want to remove that and want to display like below image

[image]

all i want is include image and list items in single rectangle

```css
.links1234 { color : #908983;}
.links1234:hover { color : #f85700;}


.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color : #fff;
  
}
.grow:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.grow ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grow img{
  width: 100%;
}

.expand 
{
 position:relative;
 right:8px;
 top:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-4.html">iPhone 4</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-4s.html">iPhone 4s</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5.html">iPhone 5</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5c.html">iPhone 5C</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html">iPhone 5S</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-6.html">iPhone 6</a></li>
<li><a class="links1234" href="/cases-covers/apple-iphone-6-plus.html">iPhone 6 Plus</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ha9pscx9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Check this [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha9pscx9/6/):

Add this to your css to have shadow over the whole box pop-up:

```
.grow:hover:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px; /* Half of the original height */
  bottom: 5px;
  left:0;
  background-color: white;
  //box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 3px white;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Also change the following parameters for `.grow ul` to:

```
box-shadow: 0 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
margin-top: 0px;
```

Check the JSFiddle code (the css) if it doesn't work for you as in example.

*Note:* You may notice that I introduced `#limheight` to reproduce the situation. However if you want to use this id for more elements you should use it as a class not as an id, because the id it's supposed to be unique on the page.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Consider this answer if you still want to use the `box-shadow`

Comment: its working fine, if you check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers.html) , if you mouse-over on `samsung` you can see pop- up , if you check image :  http://prnt.sc/cn9e5v  , there is no shadow for 3rd & 4th columns , can you please help to display shadow for line present b/w 3rd and 4th line

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 You mean you want a shadow on the top edge of the pop-up for the pop-ups with more columns?

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 I updated the code. If you have any other bug/question let me know.

Comment: i updated the code, still i dont see any shadow above 3rd and 4th column, can you check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers.html) once

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 Change `.grow:after` to `.grow:hover:after` in CSS. This should work. JsFiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/ha9pscx9/7/

Comment: you are just fantastic boss, its great the you are working on multiple platforms, Thanks a lot....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 A little suggestion. Add to the id `#limheight` this line `border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;` so the right top corner of the pop-up would be rounded. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ha9pscx9/8/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124400/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-alin-crescens-ciurea).

Answer (score 0):

remove box shadow on `.grow ul`

```
.grow ul {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/ /*Remove This*/
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: its workinjg fine in fiddle, but in site its affecting other css,   now its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/cn93i7 , before it was displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/cn93ku  , url : [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers.html)

Comment: your other images with box shadow

Comment: now i updated all images without box-shadow, but still its affecting other css

Comment: add margin-top:-14px on ".grow ul"

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
.links1234 {
       text-decoration: none;
   }

.grow li {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: i did't wanted to display line b/w image and list items, now its working fine after i followed above answer.....